# Retrieving the data using row ids and displaying in table view cells using label is making values overwritten

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sqlite, uilabel

I am able to display the correct reminders in correct cells by retrieving data from database,but the problem is 3rd reminder is getting overwritten with 2nd and 4th reminder is getting overwritten with 3rd and 3rd and 4th reminder is getting overwritten with 2nd reminder and so on.I have used different labels and added as subview to cells of table view.Here is my code,please help me to fix it

NSString *CellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[view dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellId] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {            
        //Retrieve the values of database
        const char *dbpath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;


        switch (indexPath.row) 
        {
            case 0:
            {

                UILabel *label1 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(26, 3, 30, 40)]autorelease];
                label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label2 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
                label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label3 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(119, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
                label3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label4 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(198, 3, 120, 40)]autorelease];
                label4.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label4.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM reminders"];

                    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.remindersDB ,query_stmt , -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                        {
                            NSString *ID = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]autorelease];

                            NSString *nameField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]autorelease];                    

                            NSString *eventField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]autorelease];

                            NSString *dateField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]autorelease];

                            label1.text = ID;
                            label2.text = nameField;
                            label3.text = eventField;
                            label4.text = dateField;
                        } 

                        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    }
                    sqlite3_close(self.remindersDB);
                }

                [cell addSubview:label1];
                [cell addSubview:label2];
                [cell addSubview:label3];
                [cell addSubview:label4];
            }
                break;

            case 1:
            {

                UILabel *label5 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(26, 3, 30, 40)]autorelease];
                label5.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label5.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label6 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(48, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
                label6.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label6.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label7 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(119, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
                label7.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label7.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label8 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(198, 3, 120, 40)]autorelease];
                label8.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label8.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


                if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from reminders order by id limit 1 offset 1"];

                    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.remindersDB ,query_stmt , -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                        {
                            NSString *ID = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]autorelease];

                            NSString *nameField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]autorelease];                    

                            NSString *eventField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]autorelease];

                            NSString *dateField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]autorelease];

                            label5.text = ID;
                            label6.text = nameField;
                            label7.text = eventField;
                            label8.text = dateField;
                        } 

                        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    }
                    sqlite3_close(self.remindersDB);
                }

                [cell addSubview:label5];
                [cell addSubview:label6];
                [cell addSubview:label7];
                [cell addSubview:label8];

            }

            case 2:
            {

                UILabel *label9 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(26, 3, 30, 40)]autorelease];
                label9.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label9.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label10 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(48, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
                label10.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label10.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label11 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(119, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
                label11.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label11.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label12 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(198, 3, 120, 40)]autorelease];
                label12.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label12.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from reminders order by id limit 1 offset 2"];

                    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.remindersDB ,query_stmt , -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                        {
                            NSString *ID = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]autorelease];

                            NSString *nameField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]autorelease];                    

                            NSString *eventField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]autorelease];

                            NSString *dateField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]autorelease];

                            label9.text = ID;
                            label10.text = nameField;
                            label11.text = eventField;
                            label12.text = dateField;
                        } 

                        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    }
                    sqlite3_close(self.remindersDB);
                }

                [cell addSubview:label9];
                [cell addSubview:label10];
                [cell addSubview:label11];
                [cell addSubview:label12];

            }

            case 3:
            {
                UILabel *label13 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(26, 3, 30, 40)]autorelease];
                label13.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label13.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label14 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
                label14.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label14.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label15 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(119, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
                label15.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label15.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label16 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(198, 3, 120, 40)]autorelease];
                label16.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label16.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from reminders order by id limit 1 offset 3"];

                    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.remindersDB ,query_stmt , -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                        {
                            NSString *ID = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]autorelease];

                            NSString *nameField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]autorelease];                    

                            NSString *eventField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]autorelease];

                            NSString *dateField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]autorelease];

                            label13.text = ID;
                            label14.text = nameField;
                            label15.text = eventField;
                            label16.text = dateField;
                        } 

                        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    }
                    sqlite3_close(self.remindersDB);
                }

                [cell addSubview:label13];
                [cell addSubview:label14];
                [cell addSubview:label15];
                [cell addSubview:label16];

            }
```

I am also placing screen shot that will make experts understand about the issue clear

[image]

Comment: Are you re-using "label1", "label2", etc? If they are the *same object* each pass then...

Comment: ...also, because there is no ORDER BY, the order (and thus OFFSET) cannot be relied upon.

Comment: @pst I didn't get you,but I understood one thing you were asking about,yes I am using label1,label2 etc.. for displaying and they are declared outside of switch cases :)

Comment: @pst Can u please post the correct syntax for using offset and limit

Comment: @pst Yeah even If I use ORDER BY rowid limit1 offset2 the problem still exists,any other suggestion please

Comment: Try to log the data (don't just put in UI :-) right after it is fetched and see if it agrees with what is shown. Also, check the database to make sure that the data is really as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using multiple sqlite commands for retrieving data from database. While U should to retrieve all the data in a single time and store into a mutable Dictionary and array, than get it back for table cell

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK)

{

NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from reminders"];

const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.remindersDB ,query_stmt , -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
       
             {
                       
     while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)

{
                           
 NSString *ID = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]autorelease];

NSString *nameField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]autorelease];

NSString *eventField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]autorelease];

NSString *dateField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]autorelease];

```
                    NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:ID,@"ID",nameField,@"nameField",………….];

                    [arrObj addObject:dic]; // arrObj is a mutable arr

                }
            }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
```

}
sqlite3_close(database);

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer,will get back to you after implementation

Comment: Sorry it didn't work actually,I wrote the code u gave,but it's retrieving the same values for all the cells,I mean all the cells with same reminders,Can u mention where to write the code snippet u gave